# Playing Audio using AssetFileDescriptor does not work

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

Now I'm working on Audio Player, using AssetFileDescriptor. But The song(R.raw.music3) won't play without error,, I can't find out what I did wrong,, please help me with this.

```
private void playAudio_UsingDescriptor() throws Exception{
    AssetFileDescriptor fileDesc=getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.music3);

        sound2=new MediaPlayer();
        sound2.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        sound2.setDataSource(fileDesc.getFileDescriptor());
        fileDesc.close();
        sound2.prepareAsync();
        sound2.start();

}
try {
     playAudio_UsingDescriptor();  
     }
     catch (Exception e){
                        sound2.start();
                        }
```

Comment: Why are you using prepareAsync()? Since you are trying to play a mp3 from your own resouces, you should use prepare() method and wait for MediaPlayer to be ready

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you already have your audio file in the `/res/raw` directory, try using the following to initialize your `MediaPlayer`, instead of using an `AssetFileDescriptor`:

```
sound2 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.music3);
```

Replace `MainActivity.this` with the applicable `Context` object.

Alternatively:

```
sound2 = new MediaPlayer();
AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.music3);

try
{           
    sound2.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
    afd.close();
    sound2.prepare();           
}
catch (IOException e)
{}

sound2.start();
```

Comment: Actually I have used 'MediaPlayer.create' already. I worked! What I wanna do is just to implement Audio with AssetFileDescriptor. Local audio like in my directory doesn't work with AssetFileDescriptor?

Comment: May I ask why? Just curious, as this method is quite simple, and the one I prefer. If you really want to, yes, you can do it. It'll be a combination of the answer @LazyNinja had up, and the comment above. I'll edit my answer to include it.

Comment: Just for practice cuz now I'm studying. Your answer must be helpful! I know the way you prefer is simpler. Thank you!